# What are these plants collected from the atacama desert in Chile?

Tags: identification

Can anyone tell me what this two plants are? They were found in the entrance of San Pedro de atacama in the country of Chile.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first one is very similar to one medicinal herb in my country known as *salvilla* and it is a medicinal plant that could help you for the stomachache, but I am not sure you have to check it if looks like my dear salvilla (Buddleja scordioides).

The second one is too familiar to the [Horse tail](http://delta-intkey.com/britht/www/palustre.htm) or [Equisetaceae](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equisetaceae) also equisetum. in my country is a medicina plant that help to the kidneys. In the image some varieties of this plant:

[image]

Comment: I know the horse tail… but horse tail is softer, this plant was very very hard.